# XML parsing in oracle pl/sql

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I am trying to parse this XML in PL/SQL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--ADOR Acknowledgement 2--> 
<AckTransmission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile">
  <TransmissionHeader recordCount="1">
    <Jurisdiction>ALABAMA</Jurisdiction>
    <TransmissionId>1946157056</TransmissionId>
    <Timestamp>2012-08-16T01:25:47-05:00</Timestamp>
    <Transmitter>
      <ETIN>00000</ETIN>
    </Transmitter>
    <ProcessType>T</ProcessType>
    <AgentIdentifier>ACK</AgentIdentifier>
  </TransmissionHeader>
  <Acknowledgement>
    <SubmissionId>X1684956672</SubmissionId>
    <EFIN>X16849</EFIN>
    <GovernmentCode>ALST</GovernmentCode>
    <SubmissionType>XMLTOM</SubmissionType>
    <TaxYear>9999</TaxYear>
    <SubmissionCategory>MFET</SubmissionCategory>
    <AcceptanceStatus>A</AcceptanceStatus>
    <ContainedAlerts>0</ContainedAlerts>
    <StatusDate>2012-08-16</StatusDate>
  </Acknowledgement>
</AckTransmission>
```

I am storing this XML in a table and using a function to extract data from it. But it's not successful:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (xml_list), '//@GovernmentCode/') AS SysID
  INTO lv_transid      
  FROM TABLE (
            XMLSEQUENCE (
               EXTRACT (in_xmlclob, '/AckTransmission/Acknowledgement',
                        'xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile"'))) xml_list;
```

Can you please help me to parse this XML and load into table?

Can you also please tell me how get the comment part--ADOR Acknowledgement 2--

Comment: How it is not successful?  Does it error?  If so, what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two things you have wrong here:

- Firstly, your XPath expression `//@GovernmentCode/` is wrong.  It should not have a trailing `/`, and you don't want the `@` either because `GovernmentCode` is an element, not an attribute.
- Secondly, you must specify the XML namespace declaration in your call to `EXTRACTVALUE` as well as  in your call to `EXTRACT`.

Making these changes leaves you with the following code.  I gave it a quick test, and it seemed to work:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (xml_list), '//GovernmentCode', 'xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile"') AS SysID
  INTO lv_transid      
  FROM TABLE (
            XMLSEQUENCE (
               EXTRACT (in_xmlclob, '/AckTransmission/Acknowledgement',
                        'xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile"'))) xml_list;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I have quick followup question Can you please tell me how to read comment part --ADOR Acknowledgement 2--

Comment: If you have a follow-up question, please ask it separately.  However, I will say you can't use `EXTRACTVALUE` to get at the comment text: [`EXTRACTVALUE` can only be used with text, attribute and element nodes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions054.htm).

Comment: Here is the link for new thread XML Comments parrsing Oracle http://stackoverflow.com/q/12032776/1609859?sem=2 Please Answer this Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to replace xmlns to empty string... then you can read the xml column

`xml:= regexp_replace(xml,'(xmlns:[a-z]|xmlns).*?(\"|\'').*?(\"|\'')',' ');`